# An efficient way for creating an empirical joint probability matrix by summing rows of samples according to a specified order in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, adjacency-matrix

Lets say I have a samples matrix `samples` (n_samples x n1) and a labels vector `labels` (n_samples x 1), where the labels are in the range [1:n2]

I am looking for an efficient way to create an empirical joint probability matrix `P` in the size n2 x n1.
Where for every sample `i`, we add its row `samples(i, :)` to `P` in the location indicated by `labels(i)`.

I.e. (pseudo code)

```
for i = 1:n_samples
   P(l(i), :) += M(i, :)
```

Is there a killer matlab command for doing that? Rather than a for loop or arrayfun?

Comment: I think you'll find what you need here :http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63214-how-to-use-accumarray-over-a-matrix-avoiding-a-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @BillBokeey comment: Here is the solution

```
[xx, yy] = ndgrid(labels,1:size(samples,2));
P = accumarray([xx(:) yy(:)],samples(:));
```